# Why python3.4 is trying to import module form python2.7

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have this weird problem. I have Django1.11 project using Python 3.4. I wonder why it is trying to import pandas from Python 2.7

```html
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/powrbot/company/models.py", line 3, in <module>
import pandas as pd
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
"Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
```

FYI:

```
python --version
```

is

Python 3.4.3

I run project like:

```
python manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

Numpy is already installed in 3.4

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to *.pyc file(while running project in Python 2.7) in project. Deleting all pyc files solved the issue.

The command I used to delete file is:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -exec rm -f {} \;
```