# Python is trying to import modules from a different version of Python. Rearranging Python versions in PYTHONPATH fixes it. How to make this permanent?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ubuntu, environment-variables

I have both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5. Below I have run Python 3.5, but it is looking for modules in Python 2.7. Pandas is installed for both Python versions. In order to fix this, I can rearrange the python versions in PYTHONPATH, but then Python 2.7 won't work. I want both Python versions to be able to pick up Pandas.

```
ubuntu@ip-abc: python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Jan 26 2021, 13:30:48)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    "Missing required dependencies {0}".format(missing_dependencies))
ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/ubuntu/automation', '/home/ubuntu/automation/simulation', '/home/ubuntu/aws_batch_client', '/home/ubuntu/temp', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages', '/home/ubuntu/automation/modelpool', '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python35.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.5', '/usr/lib/python3.5/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload', '/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages']
```

This is what my PYTHONPATH looks like:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/:/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
```

This is a slightly different version of my problem but the solution listed here doesn't work for me: [Why python3.4 is trying to import module form python2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48258448/why-python3-4-is-trying-to-import-module-form-python2-7)

Comment: You shouldn't need to list module destinations in your PYTHONPATH. If you do, you will encounter module compatibility issues (as you have observed). I recommend resetting your PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Which version of python? What does `sys.path` have in it? Is there something in the PYTHONPATH in this example? Since ubuntu depends on python, this could potentially be reinstal ltime (make sure to save your data).

Comment: Since PYTHONPATH is an optional environmental variable, you should be able to safely delete it.

Comment: I good rule that I don't follow myself, is to only install python extension modules from the official repos. If you want stuff that is newer, or want to use pip, do that in a Virtual Environment.

Comment: @tdelaney I am using Python 3.5 and Python 2.7. I have added sys.path and PYTHONPATH info in the question.

Comment: @Ghoti I have added only Python related info to PYTHONPATH. I have added PYTHONPATH info to the question. Can you check again?

Comment: @user5959854 Yes, but the problem with adding those paths is that they conflict depending on order and python version. Could you please try removing your PYTHONPATH variable and try to run your code again?

Comment: These paths shouldn't be in PYTHONPATH. Python already knows where its local distro paths are, PYTHONPATH is only for non-default things and should only be set  for the python you are actually using. I don't know where PYTHONPATH is set, but I think the thing to do is get rid of it. You could `export PYTHONPATH=` to clear it and see if you code runs. Then look for the .rc file that sets it to make the fix permanent.

Comment: @Ghoti clearing PYTHONPATH worked, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The solution, thanks to @Ghoti and @tdelaney from the comments: Clear the PYTHONPATH. You could export PYTHONPATH= to clear it.